# Create datetime object from numpy array floats

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have a numpy array which contains hours from 4 days:

```
s = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 ....96.0])
```

I want to create a datetime object from that.

I know that the first element is at timestamp 2021-03-21 00:00,
so:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-03-21 00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

How can I create a new array which contains datetimes, incremented by an hour from the `s` array.

Comment: you can do something like `start_date_incremented = [x + datetime.timedelta(hour = 1) for x in start_date_array]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) to build your new array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> s = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 96.0])
>>> start_date = datetime.strptime('2021-03-21 00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
>>> [start_date + timedelta(hours=diff) for diff in s]
[datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 3, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 25, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: It gives me: `unsupported type for timedelta hours component: numpy.float32`. The same if I try to convert to integers

Comment: Which Python & Numpy version are you using?

Comment: np: 1.19.2 , python:  3.7.10

Comment: Hm I'm using Numpy 1.13.3 and Python 3.6.9 but shouldn't make a huge difference. You tried `hours=int(diff)`?

Comment: Good to hear! Another option would've been to use `int_` to convert to int and then use `item` to access the Python value, like that: `[start_date + timedelta(hours=diff.item()) for diff in np.int_(s)]`